# jquery: add variable into variable

Tags: jquery

How can i add variable value into a new variable?
I'm modifying a news slider and i would like to insert "date" into subtitle

what i've tried:

```
(function( $ ){
        $.fn.accessNews = function(settings){

                $now = new Date();
                var defaults = {
                        // title for the display
                        title: "news:",
                        // subtitle for the display
                        subtitle: "$now",
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unquote it:

```
{
    // ...

    subtitle: $now,
}
```

Comment: it breaks the code `ReferenceError: $formatDate is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

subtitle: $formatDate,`

Comment: @teslasimus If you need a string value, convert your `Date` object `toString()`.